# A lot of identical staff in Comsol material database?

Tags: comsol

I got a lot of elements in `Material Browser` of `Comsol Multiphysics` of `Optics` section. Unfortunately, all data looks identical and similar to stub.

[image]

Each element has the same expression, which can be seen on screenshot.

How this should be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything unusual here. You have a material property that is defined in terms of other material properties.

In your particular case, the real and imaginary parts of the refractive index are functions defined from `n_interp` and `k_interp`, which usually denote the interpolated values (either supplied by COMSOL or user-supplied). In many simulations, you might need the refractive index to be a continuous (and maybe even differentiable function); thus, some modeling from a discrete material properties data is needed. The underlying sampled data (`n_interp` and `k_interp`) is likely different and comes from different sources for different materials.

Moreover, I would assume, that for **some** materials+data combinations, the actual functional dependence might be slightly different (in additiona to the differences in the sampled properties before interpolation); however, that is an educated guess based on properties (other than the refractive index) that I had past experience in.

Now, you might be interested in how to set up your own refractive index properties, and there are several things you can do:

- supply your own sampled data ([this might be not a bad example](https://www.comsol.com/forum/thread/40533/adding-refractive-index))
- change the expression of how you calculate the refractive index, which might be useful if you are investigating some custom materials' models or [metamaterials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamaterial).